# Best way to render some text on an image?

Tags: ros, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is/are the recommended way(s) to render some text onto an image message in ROS Indigo / Ubuntu 14.04?

I tried opencv/highgui/addText/fontQt, but that introduces an opencv compile-time dependency on qt, which is not switched on in the Debian/Ubuntu OpenCV builds which ROS depends on.

One solution is to build opencv from source and switch on the QT support, but I am worried that will be a bit of a nightmare, since the Debian opencv version is used by a bunch of stuff on my system, and ripping it out will probably break a bunch of other stuff in my ROS install.

I know I can go shop around for a generic font rendering library, but maybe there is already something that already works with ROS image messages out of the box.  I am working in Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215015/best-way-to-render-some-text-on-an-image?/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-31**:
Why should you need Qt for OpenCV? I do not get it... (well except of course using fontQt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe do it like this, it shouldn't require Qt:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html

```
string text = "Funny text inside the box";
int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
double fontScale = 2;
int thickness = 3;

Mat img(600, 800, CV_8UC3, Scalar::all(0));

int baseline=0;
Size textSize = getTextSize(text, fontFace,
                            fontScale, thickness, &baseline);
baseline += thickness;

// center the text
Point textOrg((img.cols - textSize.width)/2,
              (img.rows + textSize.height)/2);

// draw the box
rectangle(img, textOrg + Point(0, baseline),
          textOrg + Point(textSize.width, -textSize.height),
          Scalar(0,0,255));
// ... and the baseline first
line(img, textOrg + Point(0, thickness),
     textOrg + Point(textSize.width, thickness),
     Scalar(0, 0, 255));

// then put the text itself
putText(img, text, textOrg, fontFace, fontScale,
        Scalar::all(255), thickness, 8);
```

And for going to opencv use(if you do not already know):

http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-08-10**:
Thanks!  I was looking at documentation highgui (which is broken in debian stable), and which doesn't link back to the parts of the old (but actually working) C API font stuff.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-10**:
You're welcome ;-)